# why are the font names yellow instead of blue in the "font-family" property?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext

[image: font names stay yellow instead of turning blue]

i have tried putting other font names and some will turn blue but others just stay yellow. can someone explain why it is doing that?

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:normal;
```

Comment: Could you add a [mcve] to your question?

Comment: You should include your code editor (possibly as a tag if such a tag exists). What may also help is changing the `.` at the end of the font-family declaration to `;` -- what is currently shown in the picture is invalid CSS.

Comment: idk why they are highlighted blue and sans-serif is not in the above code. but on sublimetext they are not. only sans-serif is. and i changed the end . to ; and still doesn't work.

Comment: Font names here don't syntax highlight because the syntax highlighting in Sublime for CSS only highlights the predefined values of that property as defined in the CSS spec. Thus the highlighting is an indication that `sans-serif` is a predefined property while `arial` is not, even though font names are valid there. Assuming the CSS is valid, how Sublime syntax highlights it has no bearing on how the browser interprets it.

Answer (score -8):

you can try this

```css
body{
color:orange;
}
.color-blue {
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<body>

Hello<span class="color-blue">World</span>!!

</body>
```